# How to extract the highest and lowest value in array with specific condition?

Tags: php

Suppose I have inside the array this situation:

```
[0] => 4 - 0
[1] => 0 - 1
[2] => 2 - 2
[3] => 1 - 2
[4] => 0 - 0
```

The value are organized to be the first column the `home` team, and the last column the `away` team, so the first line the home team won for `4 - 0`.

Now I'm trying to extract the "best victory" that in this case is `4 - 0` and the "biggest defeat" that is `0 - 1`.

What I tried for now is iterate through the array index:

```
$biggestVictory = array_fill(0, 2, 0);
$biggestDefeat = array_fill(0, 2, 0);

foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $score = explode("-", $result);
    $home = $score[0];
    $away = $score[1];

    if($home > $biggestVictory[0] && $away <= $biggestVictory[1])
    {
        $biggestVictory[0] = $home;
        $biggestVictory[1] = $away;
    }

    if($away > $biggestDefeat [1] && $home <= $biggestDefeat [0])
    {
        $biggestDefeat [1] = $home;
        $biggestDefeat [2] = $away;
    }
}
```

this will return as result 4 - 0 for `biggestVictory` and `0 - 0` for `biggestDefeat`, why?

Comment: `0 - 1` and `1 - 2` have the same score difference. Why is `1-2` a larger defeat than `0-1`?

Comment: What is your definitions of "biggest victory" and "biggest defeat"?

Comment: So your "biggest victory" is the largest margin of victory? Would a victory of `3 - 0` be a bigger victory than `4 - 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit unclear about what "biggest victory" is actually supposed to be. Highest difference in score, or most goals scored? Assuming that the difference is what matters, this code should do the trick:

```
$biggestVictory = array_fill(0, 2, 0);
$biggestDefeat = array_fill(0, 2, 0);

foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $score = explode("-", $result);
    $home = $score[0];
    $away = $score[1];

    if( ($home - $away) >= ($biggestVictory[0] - $biggestVictory[1]) )
    {
        $biggestVictory[0] = $home;
        $biggestVictory[1] = $away;
    }

    if( ($away - $home) >= ($biggestDefeat[1] - $biggestDefeat[0]) )
    {
        $biggestDefeat [0] = $home;
        $biggestDefeat [1] = $away;
    //look at the index ^ you had a mistake in here
    }
}
```

Note that your condition `if($home > $biggestVictory[0] && $away <= $biggestVictory[1])` is pretty bad, as a `100 - 1` would not replace a `1 - 0` due to the second part of your condition.

Comment: Such a game does not need to exist. If you have a 5 - 1 and a 1 - 0, neither of them meet your requirement.

Comment: `($biggestVictory[0] - $biggestVictory[0])` will always be `0`. Did you mean to use different indexes?

Comment: Thank you, yes indeed that was a typo. It's fixed now @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

You can use Max Function to find max value in an array

> max() function returns the highest value in an array, or the highest
>   value of several specified values.

```
<?php
echo(max(2,4,6,8,10) . "<br>");
echo(max(22,14,68,18,15) . "<br>");
echo(max(array(4,6,8,10)) . "<br>");
echo(max(array(44,16,81,12)));
?>
```

And you also can use mini Function to find minimum value in an array

> The min() function returns the lowest value in an array, or the lowest
>   value of several specified values.

```
<?php
echo(min(2,4,6,8,10) . "<br>");
echo(min(22,14,68,18,15) . "<br>");
echo(min(array(4,6,8,10)) . "<br>");
echo(min(array(44,16,81,12)));
?>
```